# manipulating root URL of modules in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Suppose for `users` module when a user types `http://localhost/project/users/` URL on browser,I want to send them to `usersController@index`.For this I tried route `Route::get('users/', 'usersController@index');` but this sends to home page of xampp.There is no problem in routing `http://localhost/project/users/index` and `http://localhost/project/users` but I want to route user for `http://localhost/project/users/` as well.How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your route structure is confusing!!

Comment: @hizbul25,simply I want a route that catches URL with '/' at the end. such as 'http://localhost/project/public/index.php/users/'.

Comment: @hizbul25, I think now route structure is quite clear after I trim URL..

Comment: Take a look at the `public/.htaccess`. The default that comes with laravel redirects urls with a trailing slash. Do you want `http://localhost/project/users` and `http://localhost/project/users/` to be the same route?

Comment: @Jeemusu, yes,exactly I want `http://localhost/project/users` and `http://localhost/project/users/` to be the same route.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your routes, it is your document root folder being pointed to htdocs where the default index.php loads xammp. 
Check you the vhost settings in the v-host file
xampp\apache\conf\extra
see example

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/public"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this help.